# Getting record from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `progress` and `student`. `progress` has fields `semester`,`idStudent`,`hasFirstAttestation` and `hasSecondAttestation`.
I need to get from `progress`  those `idStudent` which have the maximum semester for student and both Attestation = 0 .
Here is an example of my query, but it is not working:

```
SELECT progress.idStudent FROM monitoring.progress 
WHERE hasFirstAttestation = 0 AND hasSecondAttestation = 0 
AND semester = 
    (SELECT MAX(`semester`)
        FROM monitoring.progress WHERE progress.idStudent = student.idStudent);
```

Comment: ***What*** in your query isn't working?

Comment: Replace the last "AND" with "IN"

Comment: remove the ' in Max().. it's MAX(semester) not MAX('semester')

Comment: I have this error: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'student.idStudent' in 'where clause'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to mention the joined table in the FROM Clause

```
SELECT idStudent 
FROM monitoring.progress 
WHERE hasFirstAttestation = 0 AND hasSecondAttestation = 0 
AND semester = (SELECT MAX(semester) FROM monitoring.progress, monitoring.student 
WHERE progress.idStudent = student.idStudent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT progress.idstudent 
FROM   monitoring.progress 
WHERE  hasfirstattestation = 0 
   AND hassecondattestation = 0 
   AND semester = (SELECT Max(`semester`) 
                   FROM   monitoring.progress,monitoring.student
                   WHERE  progress.idstudent = student.idstudent);
```